# Select maximum values from list of raster layer : ArcMap10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster

I have 10 raster layers. Each layer has the dimension of 100 columns x 100 rows and actually are temperature values from year 2000 to 2010.

I want to ask ArcMap to produce a raster layer that represent the maximum temperature value from 2000 to 2010.

Is there any function in ArcMap10 that suite to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use [Cell Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000007q000000). Load your rasters and set the statistic type to 'MAXIMUM'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Get Raster Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m7000000). Assuming you have the statistics table built for the raster, you can access quite a lot of information including max.

Rereading your question, do you just want the max value or something more?

Comment: Thanks Paul. 

That is not waht I want to do. Anyway, I just found a way to do it. Using Cell Statistics(Spatial Analyst)